# Displaying project types with Wordpress Jetpack

Tags: php, wordpress, jetpack

I'm using the Jetpack plugin with Wordpress. I've got the portfolio post type working, but now I'm trying to call the project type to display in my **content-jetpack-portfolio-single.php** file. Apparently, project types and project tags are custom taxonomies, so the usual calls for categories and tags aren't working.

The [Github repo](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/master/modules/custom-post-types/portfolios.php) uses the following code, but it's throwing up an undefined function error.

```
get_project_type();
```

I then found [this link](http://jetpack.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/jetpack_portfolioget_project_type/), which claims to display the project type with:

```
Jetpack_Portfolio::get_project_type( $post_id );
```

This produces no PHP error, but also no content, even after triple-checking the ID parameter.

I'm using Underscores as my base theme, and this code is being entered inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after a bit more hunting in the Wordpress forums, I think I found a solution, in the way of:

```
the_terms($post->ID, 'jetpack-portfolio-type');
```

Hopefully this will help anyone who is having similar problems. I had not encountered "the_terms" before, and after finding the custom taxonomy type name [from here](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/master/modules/custom-post-types/portfolios.php), it suddenly worked.

(Did I mention that I'm new to this.)